# Google Closure XhrIo problem in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, google-closure, google-closure-library

The following code doesn't work in IE, after I added the `try` block, it alerts `Error: Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce56e.`.

```
goog.require("goog.dom");
goog.require("goog.net.XhrIo");
goog.require("goog.structs.Map");
goog.require("goog.Uri.QueryData");

var errorMessage = "بروز خطا! بازیابی اخبار در این لحظه امکانپذیر نیست.";

loadPersepolisNews = function() {
  var url = 'EsteghlalNews?json=1'; 

  var request = new goog.net.XhrIo();
  goog.events.listen(request, "complete", function() {
    var container = goog.dom.$("persepolisNewsContainer");
    if (container != null && container != undefined) {        
      if (request.isSuccess()) {
        try {                  
          var json = request.getResponseJson();                            
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);          
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; ++i) {
          var news = json[i];          
          var divNews = goog.dom.createDom('div', {
            'class': i % 2 == 0 ? 'news newsEven' : 'news newsOdd'
          });

          var newsLink = goog.dom.createDom("a", {
            'href': news.url, 
            'target': '_blank', 
            'class': 'newsLink'
          }, news.title);

          var newsDate = goog.dom.createDom("span", {
            'class': 'newsDate',
            'dir': 'ltr'
          }, news.persianDate.year + '/' + news.persianDate.month + '/' + news.persianDate.day);

          goog.dom.appendChild(divNews, newsLink);
          goog.dom.appendChild(divNews, newsDate);

          goog.dom.appendChild(container, divNews);
        }
      } else {
        alert(request.getStatusText());
        var message = goog.dom.createDom('div', {
          'style': 'background-color: red; color: white; padding: 2px'
        }, errorMessage);            
        goog.dom.appendChild(container, message);  
        console.log(request.getLastErrorCode(), " - message: ", request.getLastError());
      }
    }
  });

  request.send(url, "GET");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the serverside (servlet) code.
IE is very sensitive to the `charset` value.

The **correct** one is:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

But I had written it this way: (**wrong**)

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
```